# Sending email via curl (smpt) in Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, smtp, openshift, dockerfile

I can receive email using following script locally.

```
rtmp_url="smtp://smtp.xxx.com:25"
rtmp_from="noreply@xxx.com"
rtmp_to="receiver-email@xxx.com"

file_upload="mail.txt"

echo "From: $rtmp_from
To: $rtmp_to
Subject: example of mail
Cc:
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY\"

--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY\"

--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline

This is an email example. This is text/plain content inside the mail.
--MULTIPART-ALTERNATIVE-BOUNDARY--
--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"logs.txt\"" > ./mail.txt

cat ./mail.txt | base64 >> ./mail.txt
# end of uploaded file
echo "--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY--" >> ./mail.txt

echo "sending ...."

curl --url 'smtp://smtp.xxx.com:25' --ssl-reqd   --mail-from $rtmp_from --mail-rcpt $rtmp_to  -T './mail.txt' --insecure
```

But I trying to run this script in docker container. I get this error in container :  Failed connect to smtp.xxx.com:25; No route to host.
In my pc, I changed mailhub to smtp.xxx.com in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf and so it works locally. I am new to docker and don't know how can I achieve this in docker container. Please help.

Comment: Are you doing this in an office network? Do you have your own/custom DNS server?

Comment: Yes, in office network. But I can receive emails when i run this on terminal. I don't know how do I configure in docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on your host. You will see some DNS config on your hosts. This needs to be configured for docker daemon

Create a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
"dns": ["IP1", "IP2"]
}
```

Restart the docker service and try again and see if this works for you.

You are probably on office network which has its own DNS servers that you should be using. So you need to tell the Docker daemon which DNS server its containers should be using. That is what is creating the issue. The `daemon.json` file can be used to change the daemon configuration.